# Best method to screen-scrape data off of many different websites

Tags: programming-languages, html-parsing, screen-scraping

I'm looking to scrape public data off of many different local government websites. This data is not provided in any standard format (XML, RSS, etc.) and must be scraped from the HTML. I need to scrape this data and store it in a database for future reference. Ideally the scraping routine would run on a recurring basis and only store the new records in the database. There should be a way for me to detect the new records from the old easily on each of these websites.

My big question is: What's the best method to accomplish this? I've heard some use YQL. I also know that some programming languages make parsing HTML data easier as well. I'm a developer with knowledge in a few different languages and want to make sure I choose the proper language and method to develop this so it's easy to maintain. As the websites change in the future the scraping routines/code/logic will need to be updated so it's important that this will be fairly easy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Perl with modules `WWW::Mechanize` (web automation) and `HTML::TokeParser` (HTML parsing).

Otherwise, I would use Python with the Mechanize module (web automation) and the BeautifulSoup module (HTML parsing).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David about perl and python. Ruby also has mechanize and is excellent for scraping. The only one I would stay away from is php due to it's lack of scraping libraries and clumsy regex functions. As far as YQL goes, it's good for some things but for scraping it really just adds an extra layer of things that can go wrong (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would use my own scraping library or the corresponding [command line tool](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html).

It can use templates which can scrape most web pages without any actual programming, normalize similar data from different sites to a canonical format and validate that none of the pages has changed its layout...

The command line tool doesn't support databases through, there you would need to program something...

(on the other hand [Webharvest](https://sourceforge.net/projects/web-harvest/) says it supports databases, but it has no templates)